# Which of these methods is both effective and reliable in elongate muscle and tendon for use in humans: growth factors or stem cell technology

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, literature, stem-cells, growth

Which method is it the most effective, but also the most reliable for elongating muscle and tendons for clinical trial; using modern growth factor technology or using modern stem cell technology?

Being able to stimulate muscle elongation is a key step towards improving the standard of living for people afflicted with severe Poliomyelitis or people with limb Malformations. There are already techniques to culture living bone implants in the lab from stem cells for human beings. I am looking for an analog for muscle tissue.

Please provide references with your answers.

Comment: Modern science might not know the answer to this question, and it might vary by patient. Consider narrowing down the question a little perhaps?